# How to hard code text which are coming from javascript messages

Tags: javascript, hardcoded

Our application is been internationalized and being changed to different languages. For that reason we have to hard code all the messages. How can we do that for messages in javascript ?

This is how we are doing in html messages.

```
<span th:text="#{listTable.deletedFromTable}">deleted</span>
```

How do we hard code for javascript messages.(update the table)

```
$('#TableUpdate-notification').html('<div class="alert"><p>Update the Table.</p></div>');
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Through out our application we are generating messages like success and alerts everything dynamically where all the messages are written in the property file. But some of the messages are coming from JavaScript. I didn't find a way to hard code messages from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put the messages in the `DOM` from the start, but without displaying them. Put these texts in `span` tags each with a unique `id` and the `th:text` attribute -- you could add them at the end of your document:

```
<span id="alertUpdateTable" th:text="#{listTable.updateTable}" 
     style="display:none">Update the Table.</span>
```

This will ensure that your internationalisation module will do its magic also on this element, and the text will be translated, even though it is not displayed.

Then at the moment you want to use that alert, get that hidden text and inject it where you need it:

```
$('#TableUpdate-notification').html(
'<div class="alert"><p>' + $('#alertUpdateTable').html() + '</p></div>');
```

You asked for another variant of this, where you currently have:

```
$successSpan.html(tableItemCount + " item was deleted from the table.", 2000);
```

You would then add this content again as a non-displayed `span` with a placeholder for the count:

```
<span id="alertTableItemDeleted" th:text="#{listTable.itemDeleted}" 
     style="display:none">{1} item(s) were deleted from the table.</span>
```

You should make sure that your translations also use the placeholder.
Then use it as follows, replacing the placeholder at run-time:

```
$successSpan.html($('#alertTableItemDeleted').html().replace('{1}', tableItemCount));
```

You could make a function to deal with the replacement of such placeholders:

```
function getMsg(id) {
    var txt = $('#' + id).html();
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        txt = txt.replace('{' + i + '}', arguments[i]);
    }
    return txt;
}
```

And then the two examples would be written as follows:

```
$('#TableUpdate-notification').html(
'<div class="alert"><p>' + getMsg('alertUpdateTable') + '</p></div>');

$successSpan.html(getMsg('alertTableItemDeleted', tableItemCount));
```

Comment: How we are going to handle the below scenario.                   $successSpan.html(tableItemCount + " item was deleted from the table.", 2000);

Comment: Please put this in your original question, so my modified answer will relate to it.

Comment: I have updated by answer. Influenced by your additional question I have changed the method slightly.